# Open an image in an already opened instance

Tags: c#, windows

I open some images in the default viewer, like this:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\MyPicture.jpg");
```

It works great, an image is opened but I need to display this image on a second monitor (the best option should be do it in full screen)

I thought of doing that by opening an instance of image viewer on the second monitor, set it on full screen and then run some  C# code to display images on the already opened viewer.

Maybe you know how to do that in best way? I inherited this code and I've never code in C# so any advice will be helpful.

Comment: Without any kind of IPC or knowing what kind of Command Line Switches the default program for ".jpg" supports, this won't be that easy. You could however just load the image in a window of your own.

Comment: I have to do that by the script because of some reasons. It can be even in windows viewer (windows 7). I know there is a problem with full screen, but maximized also could be ok.